# Easily connecting to the internet with FreeBSD

Tags: networking, freebsd, wifi, internet

I am a beginner at using UNIX, and I have a small Toshiba notebook computer which I installed FreeBSD 9.x on.

I looked at the [online handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/config-network-setup.html) to try to find out how to connect to the internet, but it is all really complex.  I would prefer a simple way to do this.  I have an ethernet connector, so if I really need to, do I just plug it in to the computer and router?  Is there any danger of doing anything to the router?

Comment: And what was the link you saw???

Comment: What do you mean by this.  I'm sorry if I seem very bad at this, but I have just started using Unix

Comment: Link to the page of online handbook....

Comment: I looked mainly at this one... http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/config-network-setup.html

Comment: I have an Ethernet cord...

Comment: Ok does that ethernet cord work for any other OS installed already on your system? If yes, then go ahead, and you will probably be able to find the internet connectivity. If no, then you'll need to manually install drivers for it.

Comment: I had to wipe the whole computer when I installed FreeBSD.  I also tried to connect to the network when I set it up, but it wouldn't work, probably because I didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing to remember is that getting used to something new, like a new operating system, is stressful.

Unfortunately, I haven't got freeBSD in front of me at the moment, but assuming that there is a driver for your ethernet card (which there is in all likelihood), the first thing you should try at a command prompt is,

```
ifconfig -a
```

This will show you what network interfaces you have available. Assuming that you have an ethernet interface available and it's name is `int0', you can then try

```
dhclient int0
```

which should connect you to the router. Don't forget to connect the cable up beforehand and don't worry, you can't damage the router, or your laptop, by trying this.

Comment: I had this problem on FreeBSD 11.0 running as a VHD with VirtualBox on Ubuntu 16.04. `ifconfig` shows me two interfaces, `em0` and `lo0` and `dhclient em0` worked. Now I can ping google.com. Thanks! But why is this even necessary??

Answer (score 1):

For a new user the likely easiest route is to use sysinstall.
As root:

```
#sysinstall
```

select the following (each line represents an option from menu)

```
Configure
Networking
Interfaces
```

You can skip ipv6 setup, then select DHCP.

That should configure your ethernet.

If there are multiple listings for ethernet cards (probably not in a laptop) the way to tell which one to use is from a command prompt type "ifconfig" and look for a line that looks like this:

```
media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
```

That interface has a working cable attached to it and that is the one you want to use.

To see what sysinstall did:

```
cat /etc/rc.conf
```

Later if you wanted to switch to a static IP you would edit your /etc/rc.conf to look like:

```
defaultrouter="###.###.###.###"
ifconfig_em0="inet ###.###.###.### netmask 255.255.255.0"
```

Where ### represent IPs. If you are doing this home there is a good chance your router/gateway is `192.168.1.1` and you could assign to your machine something like `192.168.1.100`.

If you have other devices and you can check what IPs they are using try to assign your FreeBSD machine an IP away from those. For example if your router is assigning IPs above 100, then setup your machine to IP of 10.