# Freebsd clean install dns problem

Tags: networking, freebsd, dns, dhcp

I would like to try FreeBSD so installed 11.1 64bit on a VirtualBox VM.

Out of the *box* there is no internet connection so as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49004/easily-connecting-to-the-internet-with-freebsd?rq=1) I did `ifconfig` and

`dhclient em0`:

> dhclient already running, pid: xxx.
>
> exiting

`ping freebsd.org`

> ping: cannot resolve freebsd.org: Host name lookup failure

`ping 8.8.8.8`

> 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=xx.xxx ms

What am I missing?  Average linux LiveCD works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Out of the box there is no internet connection

This is patently not true, given that you demonstrate packets going to and from 8.8.8.8.

> What am I missing?

You probably forgot to start your proxy DNS server.  You have a choice of several in Ports/Packages.  The *Handbook* recommends running unbound, with

```
local_unbound_enable=yes
```

in `/etc/rc.conf`.  It's that simple.  The default `resolv.conf` already points DNS client libraries at it.

I use an improved version of Bernstein's dnscache myself.

## Further reading

- "[Domain Name System](https://freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-dns.html)".  *FreeBSD Handbook*.  FreeBSD.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2000). *["content" and "proxy" DNS servers](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-server-roles.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003). *[Whence one obtains proxy DNS service](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-obtaining-proxy-service.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Daniel J. Bernstein's softwares all in one](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/djbwares/)*.  Softwares.

Comment: Many thanks!  `This is patently not true, given that you demonstrate packets going to and from 8.8.8.8.` - At first I didn't realize it's just dns that's missing, edited in `ping 8.8.8.8` part later.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer [here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-configfiles.html),

Had to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and replace `nameserver` parameter value `127.0.0.1` with a network dns server.